# How to implement a for-in loop in Objective-C from the end of collection not from beginning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-in-loop

I' m trying to iterate NSDictionary via the for in loop. But I want it to begin iteration from the end of this collection to its beginning. How can I implement this reversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mmm... the problem is that NSDictionary are unordered by nature.

So, a possible solution is make an NSArray with the keys, reverse that array with "reverseObjectEnumerator" and then make a loop over the array and use the keys on dictionary.

Something like this:

```
NSDictionary *_dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"firstValue",@"firstKey",
                       @"secondValue",@"secondKey",
                       @"thirdValue",@"thirdKey",
                       nil];

NSArray *keysNormal   = [_dict allKeys];
NSArray *keysReversed = [[[_dict allKeys] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

for(NSString *str in keysNormal)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [_dict objectForKey:str]);
}

for(NSString *str in keysReversed)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [_dict objectForKey:str]);
}
```

The log is:

- thirdValue
- secondValue
- firstValue
- firstValue
- secondValue
- thirdValue

Answer (score 7):

`NSDictionary` is an unordered data structure. There is no concept of forward iteration, or backward iteration.

When you call NSDictionary in a foreach loop, you are iterating over an unordered list of keys. When Iterating an unordered list, the order is undefined, and thus so is reversing the order. It's akin to scattering a deck of cards on the floor, then asking someone to reverse the order.

Assuming there is some order hierarchy to your keys (numeric, alphabetical, etc), You can instead get the key collection, and sort it into a particular order, and then iterate the key collection, or reverse iterate that. However if this is an operation you are doing frequently, then I suspect that `NSDictionary` is not the best choice for a datastructure for your problem.

Comment: Ok. But when i dynamically add data to it (message flow in JSON) I see that they appear in order I added them. So I want in some way to iterate my NSDictionary and catch the last message structure with particular flag in it set to 1. So I need to iterate from the end, right?
Or may be there some more logical way - I'm a newbie to Objective-C world.

Comment: The order is undefined, you can't expect the last key in the Key collection being the last element inserted into the NSDictionary. If you know you need the last message that has a flag set to one, can you just check each message as it comes in, and if it's flag is set to one, store it someone besides the NSDictionary? That way you always have fast access to the last message with `Flag=1`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray * a = @[@"a",@"b",@"c"];
NSArray * b = [[a reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
for (NSString * obj in b) {
    NSLog(@"%@",obj);
}
```

Print c,b,a.
Try to reverse the keys of your dictionary like this:

```
NSArray * key = [[[dict allKeys] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: Sort the keys first, then reverse makes sense. Otherwise as soon as you add an element to the NSDictionary, it will change the order completely.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about trying to reverse iterate a dictionary which doesn't even make any sense to begin with since dictionaries have no concept of order. Your solution for array doesn't apply to this question.